# Ultra STAMINA mode bug on Sony Xperia Z3?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery, sony-xperia, safe-mode

I had a long night yesterday, and at 5am my Xperia had like 10% of battery left, so I put it in Ultra STAMINA mode and fell asleep. This morning, the phone wouldn't turn on as the battery was completely dead. So I came home, charged the phone a little and turned it on.

Now, it's not in the safe mode, but it looks like that! The default launcher is operating, but I can't switch between none of the launchers neither. I can see only very few applications, and when I turn them on, they shut down immediately. When I reboot the phone, the first message is that Google Play Services has stopped working.

Now if I go to `Setting -> Apps`, I see everything there! Launchers, apps, games everything, also photos and contact are all there.

The Ultra STAMINA mode makes your phone use only the basic functions and I'm pretty sure it turns on the default launcher. Also connecting to computer does not work neither!

Answer (score 2):

Try charging your phone to its max and try again. This should work, do not turn on your phone until it shows that it is 100% charged. Reboot your phone and disable Ultra STAMINA mode, everything should be fine.

If your battery is less than 15%, Ultra STAMINA mode does not allow flash, camera location, 4G which requires maximum power and drain the battery.

1. Charge your battery to max
2. Reboot it
3. See the magic